# getanID function does not assign right values to groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following data frame

```
dd <- data.frame(
       date = c("2018-03-04", "2018-03-05", "2018-03-06", "2018-03-07", "2018-03-09", 
                "2018-03-11", "2018-03-15", "2018-03-16", "2018-03-17"),
       day_after_rainfall = c(1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2,3)
                 )
```

I would like to assign ids to each row based on `day_after_rainfall` -- if it continuously rains for days, those days are to be assigned the same id.

The ideal result is

```
         date day_after_rainfall .id
1: 2018-03-04                  1   1
2: 2018-03-05                  2   1
3: 2018-03-06                  3   1
4: 2018-03-07                  4   1
5: 2018-03-09                  1   2
6: 2018-03-11                  1   3
7: 2018-03-15                  1   4
8: 2018-03-16                  2   4
9: 2018-03-17                  3   4
```

I used the following code

```
library(splitstackshape)
dd <- getanID(dd, id.vars = "day_after_rainfall")
```

I get

```
         date day_after_rainfall .id
1: 2018-03-04                  1   1
2: 2018-03-05                  2   1
3: 2018-03-06                  3   1
4: 2018-03-07                  4   1
5: 2018-03-09                  1   2
6: 2018-03-11                  1   3
7: 2018-03-15                  1   4
8: 2018-03-16                  2   2
9: 2018-03-17                  3   2
```

The last two rows did not get the right ids. Why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` function:

```
dd$id <- cumsum(dd$day_after_rainfall==1)

print(dd)
#         date day_after_rainfall id
# 1 2018-03-04                  1  1
# 2 2018-03-05                  2  1
# 3 2018-03-06                  3  1
# 4 2018-03-07                  4  1
# 5 2018-03-09                  1  2
# 6 2018-03-11                  1  3
# 7 2018-03-15                  1  4
# 8 2018-03-16                  2  4
# 9 2018-03-17                  3  4
```

Comment: If you want `data.table` solution maybe `rleid` is the function to look at, but I believe it would just make the answer unnecessarily more complicated.